# Installing mysql Error: dpkg ' Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, mysql

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server;
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/75.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 86.0 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
(Reading database ... 213519 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-common (8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--configure):
 installed mysql-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-server:
 mysql-community-server depends on mysql-common (>= 8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.
  Version of mysql-common on system, provided by mysql-common:amd64, is <none>.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-client:
 mysql-community-client depends on mysql-common (>= 8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-common is not configured yet.
  Version of mysql-common on system, provided by mysql-common:amd64, is <none>.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-client:
 mysql-client depends on mysql-community-client (= 8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-client is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-client (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-community-client
 mysql-server
 mysql-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first?

Comment: yes i just made that and came up the same error.

Comment: Try `sudo touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback` and upgrade again

Comment: after trying the sudo sudo touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback and sudo apt-get upgrade; came the same Error                          Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: after trying sudo touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback; and  sudo apt-get upgrade; the Error comes up again Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please update your question with the full output , not just posting part of the output in the comments. You have a new error and I need to see all the output to help. Also please use the code boxes to format the text

Comment: Sorry it's my first time. Here goes the code

Comment: you can click [`edit`](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1070561/edit) to add the new output to the end of the answer (then select the pasted text and press ctrl+k to format it)

Comment: is the filesystem ok? do you have free space? `df -h`

Comment: Read the error messages it tells you what is missing. Now run `sudo mkdir  /etc/mysql/conf.d` and run again.

Comment: Solved. With this worked, thank you very much you're the best

Answer (score 0):

## Space

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  1.8M  787M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       458G   88G  347G  21% /
tmpfs           3.9G   77M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop2      121M  121M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-clock-app/5
/dev/loop1      2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop3       77M   77M     0 100% /snap/drakon/1
/dev/loop4       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop7       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop8      104M  104M     0 100% /snap/pac-vs/1
/dev/loop9      172M  172M     0 100% /snap/dbtarzan/5
/dev/loop11     2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/199
/dev/loop12     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/demo-curl/4
/dev/loop14      88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
/dev/loop15     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop17     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop18      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop6      147M  147M     0 100% /snap/clementine/54
/dev/loop10      87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop19      13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop20      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop13     198M  198M     0 100% /snap/vlc/365
/dev/loop16     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
/dev/loop5      172M  172M     0 100% /snap/dbtarzan/4
tmpfs           789M   16K  789M   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           789M   40K  789M   1% /run/user/1000
```

## After

```
sudo mkdir /etc/mysql/conf.d
```

## I tried  again, and

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04) ...
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 7: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Setting up mysql-server (8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04) ...
aW: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (3 vs 7).
   Affected packages: mysql-community-server:amd64
```

Comment: What did you do to get here ? Upgrade ? Ppa? Mixed repositories? Non ubuntu repositories? Now you have an apparmor problem, this is highly unusual and I cant debug your apparmor error from what little you posted

Comment: After of you ask for try to run the sudo mkdir /etc/mysql/conf.d I made and that past error dont come anymore. but come this new error and I tryid to change the repository of mysql and run again . Now I just install the mysql without errors and is working great. I think that was the Mixed repositories or non ubuntu repositories.